# Finding the sum of a Fourier series without finding the series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We are given the piecewise function 
$$ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, -\pi \leq x \lt 0 \\
x, 0 \leq x \leq \pi
\end{cases}.
$$
The function exists on interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.We are told **not** to find the Fourier series, but to find the sum of the series at several points, one of which is $\frac{\pi}{2} $. I am completely lost as to how to go about this without finding the series, but the instructions say explicitly not to do that.

Comment: Do you have any theorems about the sum of the series? I expect one of them will come in useful!

Comment: the Fourier series of a function represent the (normalized) function if this function is [piecewise continuously differentiable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Piecewise_Continuously_Differentiable_Function), what is the case. That Is: the value of the series at a point is the value of the function at this point.

Comment: if $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ the Fourrier series at $a$ will converge to $f(a).$  If $f(x)$ has a jump discontinuity at $a$ the Fourrier series will converge to $\frac 12 (\lim_\limits{x\to a^-} f(x) + \lim_\limits{x\to a^+} f(x))$